# How many classes are there in Java standard edition?

Tags: java

I am curious how many classes are there in Java standard library. Perhaps someone knows an approximate number?

Comment: I'm intrigued... why do you want to know?

Comment: Here is the list of classes added with each Java version - http://qr.ae/Q2baW

Comment: @spender No idea why Peter asked, but I asked because I'm writing a book and I wanted to contrast Java having only eight primitive types to the JDK having hundreds of reference types.

Answer (score 79):

By counting entries in the 'all classes' frame of the javadoc API:

- `4569` in [java 14](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/allclasses-index.html)
- `4545` in [java 13](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/allclasses-index.html)
- `4433` in [java 12](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/)
- `4411` in [java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/)
- `6002` in [java 10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html)
- `6005` in [java 9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html)
- `4240` in [java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)
- `4024` in [java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)
- `3793` in [java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)
- `3279` in [java 5.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/)
- `2723` in [java 1.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/)*
- `1840` in [java 1.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/)*

* Javadocs prior to 5.0 are now offline.

Comment: Javadoc only lists *public* classes - what about package private classes?

Comment: And do interfaces count as a class?

Comment: @Nate I'm don't see it as relevant, since non-public classes are unusable, and their count will vary based on implementation yet have no affect on the size of the visible API.

Comment: @Steve-Kuo yes, in these counts all public classes, abstract classes, and interfaces are counted.

Comment: @Chadwick - Yes, but the question didn't specify *usable* classes - just classes - so there's no way to determine if it's relevant or not.  Sorry :P - overly literal/legalistic interpretation because I'm so used to wrangling over requirements and specifications has broken me.  Or maybe it's just Asperger's...

Comment: i guess in java 7 the number is 4024!!

Comment: The number of classes is increasing until Java 9, and drastically reduced in Java 11. I'm naive about this, did Java 11 remove a lot classes?

Comment: @AryanVenkat you could say they "removed" them. Or you could say they simplified them. Remember the time package before Java 8? It was a monster. Take like 10 lines of code to get a slightly buggy time program to work in Java 7 which you could do in a single action in 8.

Comment: How did you counted? @Andreas

Comment: @AryanVenkat Many things were [removed in Java 11](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#Removed), mainly JavaFX, and the Java EE (JAX-WS, JAXB, JAF, JTA, ...) and CORBA Modules ([*JEP 320*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320)). All of that, except CORBA, is now available separately.

Comment: At the risk of further hair-splitting, private classes are usable, just not directly usable. Presumably the JDK contains no unused private classes. I'm also guessing this count does not include anonymous classes. Even with these caveats, this is still very interesting information and I thank you for it.

Comment: Hmm, there was a significant spike with Java 9, a slight dip for Java 10 and a significant dip for Java 11. I wonder if Java 15, 16 and 17 show a continued trend of slight increases...

Answer (score 16):

I'm also curious about this topic. I found this:
[image]

(source: [Java 8 Pocket Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033318.do) book by  Robert Liguori, Patricia Liguori)

Answer (score 5):

- Java 1.0.2 : 250 classes
- Java 1.1   : 500 classes
- Java 2 (version 1.2-1.4) : 2300 classes
- Java 5.0 (version 1.5) : 3500 classes

Source : Head First 2nd edition, Chapter 1, p. 4

Comment: The Java API has grown quite a bit since v1.0.

Answer (score 4):

I counted 17,338 in Java 6.0.  My methodology:

```
jar -tf ${JAVA}/jre/lib/rt.jar > rtjar.txt
emacs rtjar.txt
```

I deleted two lines related to the manifest (and thus not representing a class).  I believe that the other lines all refer to classes, but I did not do an exhaustive check.  Then I went to the bottom of the file and emacs told me that there 17,338 lines.

This includes stuff like:  java/io/ObjectOutputStream$1.class.

Answer (score 3):

I see [3793](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) counting interfaces and abstract classes, as well as private classes.

Answer (score 1):

I see 3762 within Java 8 as following

```
All Classes ( Outer as well as Inner ) , Enums and Interfaces -  3762
All except Inner Classes                                      -  3462
Only Classes ( Outer + Inner + Abstract + Enum )              -  2963
Interfaces                                                    -  799
Enum                                                          -  93
```

Moreover , Here is the list of classes / interfaces introduced with each version - http://qr.ae/Q2baW

Answer (score 1):

For Java SE 9 , according to the API doc 6005 including abstract and interfaces.

For Java SE 10, according to the API doc 6002 including abstract and interfaces.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html

Method : view source, and count "<li>" html tag with notepad++.

For Java SE 11, according to the API doc 4411 including abstract and interfaces.

For Java SE 12, according to the API doc 4433 including abstract and interfaces.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/allclasses-index.html

Method : view source, and count "colFirst" css class with notepad++

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation 3793 including abstract classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating classes and subclasses is a cumbersome task, but you can know the number of files. 4240 total files in Jdk 8. Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html) for the list of all files.

Comment: I have provided the answer and just added the link for reference. Link is not the answer.