# Why would you choose Squeak over Pharo today?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I am trying to understand the uses of both. Already I have seen stuff on the SmalltalkHub doesn't often build on Squeak but always seems to work with Pharo. What are the advantages now in 2014 to choose Squeak and not Pharo?

Comment: I think that you will get a lot of different opinions. For me it always looks like Squeak people never wanted to make something cool that can be broadly used. But this is a personal opinion. Look for existing products.

Comment: The Magma developer uses Squeak, so it tends to have the opposite problem of building on Squeak but not Pharo.

Comment: I would liken it loosely to Linux vs BSD. The Pharo folks have big dreams and want to embrace lots of new things. So you've seen some vibrant development in the Pharo fork, some good, some a complete waste. The Squeak guys (due in part to some invested projects such as SqueakToys etc) were less interested in constant change for the new, and wanted some stability. So Pharo, like Linux, tends to be a little more inclusive and gets bigger public buy in, and Squeak like BSD is the more conservative but stable variant.

Comment: I also think this is a great question, and I think the SO moderators should lighten up a little. It's not like the ailing Smalltalk community is going to generate huge amounts of traffic here anyway.

Comment: From my experience, both are cool and have their pros and cons. I find Pharo more active for things like web development, and Squeak a better fit for educational use -- with lots of built in graphics tools. E.g. try this `SketchMorph openEditor.` in Squeak, or `Pen new hilberts: 4.`

Comment: I have chosen Pharo for various reason, mostly because is very actively developed. I would have chosen Squeak because some of the libraries. I still go back to Squeak to take a look at some very cool code, for example I love music, so the fm synthesizer is definetly very interesting. I love graphics , Etoys comes with tons of useful functionality. So I would say a big reason to use Squeak is of course its libraries, it has a ton of them and many of them are quite mature and well tested. Its also possible to use both at the same time , Pharo and Squeak , the best of both worlds.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426981/squeak-or-pharo-for-the-beginning-smalltalker