# What are the immutable objects other than String inside Java?

Tags: java, immutability

Strings are immutable, other than them, what are the objects which are immutable in java?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112882/how-many-classes-are-there-in-java-standard-edition there are 4240 classes in Java. Do you want someone to iterate over all classes and find immutable ones? Really?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examples of immutable classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124012/examples-of-immutable-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short
```

are some of the objects that are immutable.